# Why parcel does not update/watch imported modules? and how can i fix it?

Tags: javascript, typescript, parcel

i am trying to build a [js library](https://github.com/nachat-ayoub/js-2d-game-engine), but i faced a problem during the developing stage, which is [parcel](https://parceljs.org/) does not update/watch imported modules from my library which i linked using `yarn link` command, but after i kill the serve (test project server) and start it again it works with latest changes i made in the library.

### some info about my project:

**- project structure :**

```
 lib/
  |  |- package.json
  |  |- src/
  |  |  |- core/
  |  |  |  |- Game.ts
  |  |  |  |- index.ts
  |  |  |  |- InputManager.ts
  |  |  |- index.d.ts
  |  |  |- index.ts
  |  |- tsconfig.json
  |  |- yarn.lock
 test/
  |  |- package.json
  |  |- src/
  |  |  |- index.html
  |  |  |- main.ts
  |  |- yarn.lock
 README.md
```

**- lib/pacakge.json :**

```json
{
  "name": "js-2d-game-engine",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "src/index.ts",
  "repository": "https://github.com/nachat-ayoub/js-2d-game-engine.git",
  "author": "nachat-ayoub",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "parcel src/index.ts --no-cache",
    "build": "parcel build src/index.ts"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.5",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  }
}
```

**- test/pacakge.json :**

```json
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "source": "src/index.html",
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "nachat-ayoub",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "parcel --port 3000",
    "build": "parcel build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "^2.8.3"
  }
}
```

I tried **"--no-cache --no-autoinstall"** flags in the parcel command, but still the same problem.